# How to separate string from a long string in php

Tags: php

i have a string like

```
1~anil~anil@gmail.com~9999111132~2~nikhil~nikhil@gmail.com~047027282~3~nimmy~nimm@gmail.com~9127282
```

And the results should be

```
1~anil~anil@gmail.com~9999111132
2~nikhil~nikhil@gmail.com~047027282
3~nimmy~nimm@gmail.com~9127282
```

Comment: Is the result an array or just 3 lines of text?

Comment: you should tell in what form the result you expected also.

Comment: result should be in array form

Comment: also help me to store this result to an array with keys like array("id","name","email","mobileno");

Comment: how to insert this new array values to a database table?

Answer (score 2):

Something simple like this would do it

```
$in = '1~anil~anil@gmail.com~9999111132~2~nikhil~nikhil@gmail.com~047027282~3~nimmy~nimm@gmail.com~9127282';

$bits = explode('~', $in);

$newArr = [];

for ($i=0; $i<count($bits); $i+=4){
    // if you want results in an array
    $newArr[] = sprintf('%s~%s~%s~%s', $bits[$i], $bits[$i+1], $bits[$i+2], $bits[$i+3]);
}
print_r($newArr);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1~anil~anil@gmail.com~9999111132
    [1] => 2~nikhil~nikhil@gmail.com~047027282
    [2] => 3~nimmy~nimm@gmail.com~9127282
)
```

COMMENT ADDITION

Just change the code in the for loop to make an array in the format you like

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($bits); $i+=4){
    $newArr[] = ['id'=> $bits[$i],
                 'name'=> $bits[$i+1],
                 'email'=> $bits[$i+2],
                 'mobileno'=> $bits[$i+3]
      ];
}
```

RESULT NOW

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => anil
            [email] => anil@gmail.com
            [mobileno] => 9999111132
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => nikhil
            [email] => nikhil@gmail.com
            [mobileno] => 047027282
        )
    [2] => Array (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => nimmy
            [email] => nimm@gmail.com
            [mobileno] => 9127282
        )
)
```

Comment: how to store this result to an array with keys like array("id","name","email","mobileno");

Comment: while inserting these new array to database, this mobile no filed is encrypted and add different number to database .Why this problem is occur ? how to solve this ? Help me